# How to make the ListFragment items wider?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have created a custom list fragment. Here is the code and the screenshot of how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/mail_read_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mail_from_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mail_read_checkbox"
    android:text="aa"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mail_subject_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mail_from_textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mail_read_checkbox"
    android:text="bb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

My question is, how can i make each list item wider? I mean this: my list items are like this now:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
From: ...
Subject: ...
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i want them to look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------

From: ...

Subject: ...

--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add Top and bottom Margin (or Padding) to your views using dp.

i.e.:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mail_from_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:marginTop="5dp"
    android:marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mail_read_checkbox"
    android:text="aa"/>
```

For more info, here's the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html).